# KDB+ Cast symbol to char

Tags: casting, kdb

I have a table containing file paths in `symbol` format as follows:

```
t : ([]date:"d"$til 5; filepath:`aaa.pdf`bbb.pdf`ccc.pdf`ddd.pdf`eee.pdf)

date       filepath
-------------------
2000.01.01 aaa.pdf 
2000.01.02 bbb.pdf 
2000.01.03 ccc.pdf 
2000.01.04 ddd.pdf 
2000.01.05 eee.pdf
```

I want to convert column `filepath` to `char`, but the following are not working:

```
update "c"$filepath from t

update {"c"$x} each filepath from t
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `string` key word.

```
q)update string filepath from t
date       filepath 
--------------------
2000.01.01 "aaa.pdf"
2000.01.02 "bbb.pdf"
2000.01.03 "ccc.pdf"
2000.01.04 "ddd.pdf"
2000.01.05 "eee.pdf"
```